# Change fragments textview from activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to change fragments textview from activity(not fragment class).How can I do it ? I am using this code:

```
public void startChat() {
    FrameLayout layout = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.container);
    layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container, new ConversationFragment());
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
    viewPager.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    TextView nameView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.user_name);
    nameView.setText("asd");
}
```

This code loads conversation_fragment.xml and wants change textview,but my app is crashing.

Here conversation_fragment.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#878787" >

        <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="dfgdfgdf"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:id="@+id/user_name"/>

    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/message"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   />

    <Button 
        android:text="Gönder"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="getFromUser"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: you should wait for `onCreateView` to be finished, after that you are allowed to call `findViweById`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either use `findFragmentById` to find your fragment and call a public method that changes the text

```
(ConversationFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.yourid);
```

or keep an instance of the class when you create it before you add it to the fragment manager

```
conv = new ConversationFragment()
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container, conv);
```

then just call the public method using `conv` or whatever you call it

**EDIT:**

you use a bundle to send in data to the fragment

```
Bundle b = new Bundle()
b.putString("text",data)
conv.setArguments(b);
```

then in your fragment get the arguments with `getArguments()` and pull the data from the bundle and use it however you need

Comment: wait are you trying to change the textview when you create the fragment?

Comment: I didn't understand this line:b.putString("text",data) also I have to update an imageview how can I do it ? Can you give an example ?

Comment: How can I use it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39907625/why-is-accessing-textview-of-a-fragment-inside-activity-throwing-an-error

Answer (score 1):

You can make like this

```
public class ConversationFragment extends Fragment {

    private TextView nameView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.conversation_fragment, null);
        nameView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.user_name);
    }

    public void setText(String yourText){
        nameView.setText(yourText); 
    }
}
```

and in your activity call method **setText()**

```
ConversationFragment conv = new ConversationFragment();
conv.setText("asd");
```

With best regards.

Comment: I am getting this error:http://prntscr.com/49j4h8

I defined setText function fragment class.

Comment: It's a bit strange. Can you provide more details about your problem?

Comment: I can't use these function from activity.Fragment class:http://prntscr.com/49jxap

Comment: I get a NPE error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39907625/why-is-accessing-textview-of-a-fragment-inside-activity-throwing-an-error Can you please help