# changing fragment's textview from activity does not update UI

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-databinding

I am attempting to do something that seems common practive (f.i. here, [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25123336/change-fragments-textview-from-activity)). But while the data is transmitted and can be put f.i. into a viewmodel, android does not seem to care that I have changed the text of a textview. This is my code (I prefer databinding over findviewbyid):

Activity:

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(String param) {
    MainFragment oFragment = (MainFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(MainFragmentTag);
    if(oFragment != null) {
        oFragment.SetText(param);
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(oBinding.mainContainer.getId(), oFragment)
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();
    }
}
```

Receiving Fragment:

```
public void SetText(String param) {
    String sInput = oBinding.MyInputField.getText().toString();

    oBinding.TextviewIWantToChange.setText(param);
    Entry oEntry = Manager.CreateEntry(sInput, param);
    viewmodel.Insert(oEntry);
}
```

The old fragment instance shows up, the right param is transmitted and viewmodel insertion works smoothely. But the textview is not updated. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Pass your data with Fragment arguments and read another fragment getArguments

```
@Override
                public void onItemSelected(String param) {
                    MainFragment oFragment = (MainFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(MainFragmentTag);
                    if(oFragment != null) {

                        Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
                        bundle.putString("param",param);
                        oFragment.setArguments(bundle);
                        getSupportFragmentManager()
                                .beginTransaction()
                                .replace(oBinding.mainContainer.getId(), oFragment)
                                .addToBackStack(null)
                                .commit();
                    }
                }
```

// Call this on which fragment you have need

```
public void SetText(String param) {
        String sInput = oBinding.MyInputField.getText().toString();

        oBinding.TextviewIWantToChange.setText(param);
        Entry oEntry = Manager.CreateEntry(sInput, param);
        viewmodel.Insert(oEntry);
    }
```

Call thi methhod on OnCreateView

```
final Bundle bundle = getArguments();
 String param = bundle.getString("param");
```

Comment: Thank you man, this works! I wonder though - is it only possible to manipulate view in the OnCreateView method? This seems quite limiting, f.i. when I use two fragments side by side and the fragment I want to update is not recreated via commit.